# Matlab start parallel parpool failed and checked SPDM validation failed with no message

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Parallel failed when I using the parpool on my HP Z820，The Parallel pool could run on my laptop ,they are same OS Win7, And I try to reinstall the matlab, Z820 respond same message below is the message:

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... 
    Error using parpool (line 103)
    Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile 'local'
    in the Cluster Profile Manager.)

    Error in parallel.internal.ui.PoolHelper.startPool (line 11)
                parpool();

    Caused by:
        Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowWithCause (line 667)
        Failed to initialize the interactive session.
            Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowIfBadParallelJobStatus (line 768)
            The interactive communicating job failed with no message.
```

Validation reply :

SPMD job test（createCommunicationJob） Failed The job errored or did not reach state finished.

Anyone could help? 
BestRegards

```
VALIDATION DETAILS
Profile: local
Scheduler Type: Local

Stage: Cluster connection test (parcluster)
Status: Passed
Description:Validation Passed
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: Job test (createJob)
Status: Passed
Description:Validation Passed
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: SPMD job test (createCommunicatingJob)
Status: Failed
Description:The job errored or did not reach state finished.
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:
LOG FILE OUTPUT:

Stage: Pool job test (createCommunicatingJob)
Status: Skipped
Description:Validation skipped due to previous failure.
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: Parallel pool test (parpool)
Status: Skipped
Description:Validation skipped due to previous failure.
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)
```

Comment: Yeah, trust Matlab and validate the profile 'local' in the cluster profile Manager: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/clusters-and-cluster-profiles.html#brrzq8d-1

Comment: validation reply:The job errored or did not reach state finished.

Comment: Most likely you get much more things are than that error. Can you put all the possible information the validation gives?

Comment: I have update the validation below the original question

Comment: Nice. Before continuing, please try to check if all the installation and configuration of the computer is right. There is a very big and extended explanation of how to do this in the following link: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92124-why-am-i-unable-to-use-matlabpool-or-parpool-with-the-local-scheduler-or-validate-my-local-configura#answer_101475

Comment: Also, check that the firewall allows Matlab, mpiexec and smpd do whatever they want. I am 95% sure that this is the reason.

Comment: I have tried the link,it still not works.Also, I start some windows services to make sure the Z820's windows services is same as my laptop.
I found here is only one service can't be start: ICS internet connection Sharing。I don't know if it is a problem，I'm trying